# What does "sparkle" mean in this: "Vampires Don't Sparkle"

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

What does it mean when one says a vampire sparkles?
As I know, sparkling means: "shine brightly with flashes of light".

The phrase in question is "not all who sparkle are vampires" in the book [Data Smart: Using Data Science to Transform Information into Insight](https://books.google.com/books?id=CfjpAQAAQBAJ&pg=PP10&lpg=PP10&dq=data+smart+not+all+who+sparkle+are+vampires&source=bl&ots=Sx5EySPMlZ&sig=EzK0ZX9bux8gvizI28jq3xrWBKc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjniM3UjfTZAhViGsAKHer5CBoQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=data%20smart%20not%20all%20who%20sparkle%20are%20vampires&f=false).

Comment: Where did you get this? Do you have a citation? Please add a link, otherwise it might just be guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an allusion to the saying "all that glitters isn't gold".

The idea of sparkling vampires comes from the Stepahnie Meyer's [Twilight Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Saga_(film_series)):

> Due to the crystalline properties of their cells, when a vampire is exposed to sunlight, their body will sparkle like diamonds.
>   (Source: [Twilight Saga Wiki](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire))

Comment: The last element of the context in the source is that it is discussing a group of wine drinkers who prefer Champagne and other sparkling (=bubbly) wines.